# Unity-Android-App Crashes when Run First Time but From Second Time it Works Fine

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, exception, crash

I have implemented Firebase Analytics and Firebase Messaging after download the plugin from Google we site and successfully running the Resolvers.
The problem is after build when App is Run FIRST TIME it crashes with the following error but from 2nd time onwards the app does not crash 
Here is the log

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.lemontart.flying.robot.car.transformation, PID: 27861
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.google.firebase.messaging.cpp.ListenerService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.messaging.cpp.ListenerService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.lemontart.flying.robot.car.transformation-EVwlnR7Mxf4TO-7_HvK44w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.lemontart.flying.robot.car.transformation-EVwlnR7Mxf4TO-7_HvK44w==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.lemontart.flying.robot.car.transformation-EVwlnR7Mxf4TO-7_HvK44w==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3654)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.messaging.cpp.ListenerService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.lemontart.flying.robot.car.transformation-EVwlnR7Mxf4TO-7_HvK44w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.lemontart.flying.robot.car.transformation-EVwlnR7Mxf4TO-7_HvK44w==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.lemontart.flying.robot.car.transformation-EVwlnR7Mxf4TO-7_HvK44w==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:169)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateService(AppComponentFactory.java:103)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3649)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:207) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService;
        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
                ... 11 more
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService
        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                ... 14 more
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class com.google.firebase.iid.zzb extended by class com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService is inaccessible (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService' appears in base.apk)
                ... 14 more
2019-05-17 12:55:18.960 27861-27861/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.lemontart.flying.robot.car.transformation, PID: 27861
    java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
    Unity version     : 2018.3.14f1
    Device model      : OnePlus ONEPLUS A5000
    Device fingerprint: OnePlus/OnePlus5/OnePlus5:9/PKQ1.180716.001/1904191514:user/release-keys

    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.google.firebase.messaging.cpp.ListenerService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.messaging.cpp.ListenerService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.lemontart.flying.robot.car.transformation-EVwlnR7Mxf4TO-7_HvK44w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.lemontart.flying.robot.car.transformation-EVwlnR7Mxf4TO-7_HvK44w==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.lemontart.flying.robot.car.transformation-EVwlnR7Mxf4TO-7_HvK44w==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3654)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.messaging.cpp.ListenerService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.lemontart.flying.robot.car.transformation-EVwlnR7Mxf4TO-7_HvK44w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.lemontart.flying.robot.car.transformation-EVwlnR7Mxf4TO-7_HvK44w==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.lemontart.flying.robot.car.transformation-EVwlnR7Mxf4TO-7_HvK44w==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:169)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateService(AppComponentFactory.java:103)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3649)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:207) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService;
        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
```

I an see there are all the jars and aars present it the project, still I am not able to figure our the problem.
Here is my gradle file

```
// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
**BUILD_SCRIPT_DEPS**}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

// Android Resolver Repos Start
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com/" // Assets/Consoliads/Editor/ConsoliAdsDependencies.xml:7
        }
        maven {
            url "file:////Volumes/JawadData/Unity%20Projects/Consoli%204.6.2%20Unity%202018/Assets/Firebase/m2repository" // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AnalyticsDependencies.xml:22, Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:22
        }
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
// Android Resolver Repos End
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
**APPLY_PLUGINS**

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

**DEPS**}

android {
    compileSdkVersion **APIVERSION**
    buildToolsVersion '**BUILDTOOLS**'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion **MINSDKVERSION**
        targetSdkVersion **TARGETSDKVERSION**
        applicationId '**APPLICATIONID**'
        ndk {
            abiFilters **ABIFILTERS**
        }
        versionCode **VERSIONCODE**
        versionName '**VERSIONNAME**'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress = ['.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb'**STREAMING_ASSETS**]
    }**SIGN**

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled **MINIFY_DEBUG**
            useProguard **PROGUARD_DEBUG**
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD**
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled **MINIFY_RELEASE**
            useProguard **PROGUARD_RELEASE**
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD****SIGNCONFIG**
        }
    }**PACKAGING_OPTIONS****SPLITS**
**BUILT_APK_LOCATION**
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        density {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        abi {
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }
}**SPLITS_VERSION_CODE****REPOSITORIES****SOURCE_BUILD_SETUP**
```

I need to fix this issue, please help it will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide some information about: Your Unity version, the platform you're building for, the runtime you're using, and wether it is a development build or not (if you tried both, does it make a difference)?

Comment: Unity 2018.3.14F for Android. I had to go to previous version of Firebase and it fixed the issue. It was a release build with Split APK Option for ARMv7 and 64 Bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few days ago I faced the same issue, And it was resolved by just updating The all firebase libraries to their latest version. It seems that their could be version conflict between the dependencies. 
You can find the latest versions list of the Firebase libraries [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)

Comment: the issue was fixed by revering to previous version of Firebase in my case Latest version of Firebase was causing the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line to your gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+'
```

I think it should to the end of the document, if not try in other places like this:

```
    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+'
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

**DEPS**}
```

Or here:

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+'
**BUILD_SCRIPT_DEPS**}
}
```